# Manipulating a class element in the DOM using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Stuck on this question for manipulating the DOM using jQuery for a while now I get an error the class featured was present when it shouldn't be.

```
/*
For this quiz, use a jQuery class selector and featuredArticle variable to toggle the 'featured' class!
*/

// don't change this variable!
var featuredArticle;


my anwser =>
featuredArticle = //$('.featuredArticle');

//featuredArticle.toggleClass('.featured')
```

Comment: `toggleClass` takes a class name, not a selector. Remove the period in front of `featured`

Comment: What is the error? And what are you expecting it to do?

Comment: The compiler tells me that that the class featured was present when it shouldn't have been.